Mutt: auto-reply with template?
In Mutt, I would like to configure something akin to the "Reply with Template" message filter action from Thunderbird. I.e., for a given message, I would like to be able to easily (read: keyboard shortcut) send a reply with predefined subject and body. Is this even possible?
Thanks.

I don't believe that mutt has that capability, but I may be wrong.  What environment are you working in? Just wondering whether you could tie such a template to a key-combo outside mutt ...

Thanks. In that case I'll just have to continue doing this manually. As for the environment, I am using multiple DEs across multiple machines (mainly LXQt and KDE, but some machines are headless). It is a pity that -- as far as my hitherto online research has revealed -- one can't in Mutt easily pass a message source as an argument to an external command.

For completeness' sake: the best -- but still rather clunky -- approach that I have come up with thus far is defining one vimscript function (replaces the reply text with a predefined template read from a file; I am using vim as my editor) and one Mutt macro for the compose screen (changes the message subject).

Nice work, @nvx :)  You could make that a self-answer.

Nah, it is a half-baked workaround instead of a single-keyboard-shortcut solution (as stipulated in the original post). I'll post back if I find something better.

I have come up with a solution requiring Vim (my editor of choice) plus a Vimscript function, a simple Bash script, and a template file. This ensures that the text is properly encoded (e.g., format=flowed), because Mutt actually processes the file saved by the text editor (search for "Space-stuffing" in the Mutt Manual).
A (perhaps) better solution implemented solely in Mutt is in the works, but for the reasons listed in Mutt: how to disable specifying the filename for a single inline plain text attachment? still is not polished enough. Moreover, the attached text file -- the template reply -- would not be processed in any way, which could possibly cause problems to the recipients.
Anyway, the Vimscript function (stored in ~/.vimrc) replaces the reply text prepared by Mutt with the text from the template file:
function! AutoReply()
  %d_
  r /path/to/template
  0d_
  wq
endfunction

The first line deletes everything (to the black hole register), the second one reads the template text from the template file, the third line removes the leading empty line inserted by read (r; again, to the black hole register), and the last line saves the file and quits Vim.
The Bash script (~/.mutt/vim-auto-reply) is used as a temporary replacement for Mutt's editor, and ensures that the function above is called as a Vim autocommand:
#!/bin/bash
vim $1 "+:call AutoReply()"

The single-keypress Mutt macro (bound to Esc-a in this example) then reads as follows:
macro index,pager \ea "<enter-command>set editor=~/.mutt/vim-auto-reply<enter><reply><edit-from><kill-line>Do Not Reply <noreply@domain.tld><enter><edit-subject><bol><delete-char><delete-char><delete-char><delete-char>Automatic Reply (was: <eol>)<enter><send-message>a<enter-command>set editor=vim<enter>" "Auto-reply + archive"

Let's unpack the commands:

<enter-command>set editor=~/.mutt/vim-auto-reply<enter>: temporarily sets the editor to our script (to replace the contents of the message with the template and immediately quit Vim),
<reply>: replies to the selected message (requires set fast_reply),
<edit-from><kill-line>Do Not Reply <noreply@domain.tld><enter>: replaces the sender in the From header with a suitable value,
<edit-subject><bol><delete-char><delete-char><delete-char><delete-char>Automatic Reply (was: <eol>)<enter>: changes the subject (e.g., "Original subject" --> "Automatic Reply (was: Original subject)"), the four <delete-char>s delete the "Re: " added by Mutt upon replying,
<send-message>: sends our auto-reply,
a: archives the original message,
<enter-command>set editor=vim<enter>: restores our original editor.

Note that the closing parenthesis in the message subject must be added as the last character. The reason is that for an empty original subject, the reply subject generated by Mutt is "Re:" (i.e., three characters). In other words, with <edit-subject>)<bol>...(was: <enter>, one would get "Automatic Reply (was: " instead of "Automatic Reply (was: )".
The penultimate command (a) ties to my archive macro that also marks the message as read (the only difference between Index and Pager is the leading i):
macro index a "<enter-command>set resolve=no<enter><clear-flag>N<enter-command>set resolve=yes<enter><save-message>=Archive<enter>" "Archive message (mark as read)"
macro pager a "i<enter-command>set resolve=no<enter><clear-flag>N<enter-command>set resolve=yes<enter><save-message>=Archive<enter>" "Archive message (mark as read)"

Again, let's unpack what we have here:

<enter-command>set resolve=no<enter>: we do not want to advance to the next message after carrying out the following step,
<clear-flag>N: clears the New flag (i.e., marks the message as read),
<enter-command>set resolve=yes<enter>: restores the original behaviour (to advance to the next message whenever a command that modifies the current message is executed),
<save-message>=Archive<enter>: saves the original message to the archive folder,
the leading i for the Pager: skips to the Index first (needed for the rest to work properly).

Usage: just press Esc-a in the Index or Pager. :)
